# How to make resizable line with jQuery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, line, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

About the resizable stuff, I know about [resizable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) widget from jQuery and I used to use it for div.

But, is there any way to make something like a resizable line with jQuery-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see line as `div` with `height: 1px`. Than simply use UI code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".line").resizable({
    minWidth: 150,
    maxWidth: 300,
    handles: 'e, w'
  });
});
```

```css
.line {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @justinas , but why it has something like a maximum length when I tried to resize it?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji If my answer solves your issue please accept it as answer

Comment: Ok, I will. But just one more question. Based on your instance, when I resized it, why it has something like a maximum length? Is there any way to make it resizable without any limitation?

Comment: Omg, it's my mistake. I found it. it's the setting of the resizable. Thanks!